# Debug not working on Spring Boot 2.7.3 application in STS (Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, debugging

I have a REST API created on Spring Boot 2.7.3 that I'm testing through Postman.

When I run the application through STS, it starts fine and I get the correct responses on Postman.

But when I run it on Debug mode in STS, the application doesn't start fine and I get a "Could not send request" error message on Postman as if no application was up and running.

I noticed that in STS, when running in debug mode, the last message I see in the console is "HHH000400: Using dialect...." as you see in the screen shot below.

[image]

On the other hand, in another application that debug is working fine (earlier Spring Boot version) the last message I see is "Started Application in x seconds (JVM running for 12.133)" as you see in this other screen shot below.

[image]

So seems that the first application is not correctly starting in debug mode.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an STS issue or an application properties issue? Ensure you have your package logging level set correctly.

Examples:

application.yaml

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    com.myself.app: debug
```

or application.properties

```
logging.level.com.myself.app=debug
```

Comment: Understand I should replace com.myself.app in your suggestion by my own groupid.artifactid, correct? I tried that but did not work. Same results. It's not an STS issue for sure. It's an application issue (maybe Spring Boot version issue). I say that because the second application that I mentioned that is working fine, it being ran in the same STS IDE just changing the workspace.

Comment: Yes, correct, sorry. Change the `com.myself.app` to your package.